# 'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, r, shell, cmd, path

```
shell_exec("Rscript C:\R\R-3.2.2\bin\code.R ");
```

This is the call to script.On calling the above script, the error occurs.

I am trying to call my R script from the above path but no output is being shown. While checking the error logs of PHP, it says 'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.' The script is working fine on the Rstudio but not running on the command line.

Comment: Please be more descriptive and also attach the error that you are getting

Comment: You could try something like this in the command prompt:

`cd C:\R\R-3.2.2\bin\ & Rscript "C:\R\R-3.2.2\bin\code.R"`, or possibly: `cd C:\R\R-3.2.2\bin\ & Rscript code.R`. Basically, use `cd` to change directory to the location of your Rscript.exe, then run a second command using `&` with the Rscript and the path to your script.

Comment: Another option is include the path as part of the Rscript command: "C:\R\R-3.2.2\bin\Rscript" C:\R\R-3.2.2\bin\code.R

Comment: @Dave2e Thanks....that solved the problem :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add the `Rscript` path to your environment variables in Windows:

Go to Control Panel\System and Security\System and click Advanced System Settings, then environment variables, click on path in the lower box, edit, add "C:\R\R-3.2.2\bin"

Restart everything.  Should be good to go.  Then you should be able to do

`exec('Rscript PATH/TO/my_code.R')`

instead of typing the full path to `Rscript`.  Won't need the path to your my_code.R script if your php file is in the same directory.

Comment: Is it the _user_ or _system_ environment variables?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the proper path where your RScript.exe program is located.

```
exec ("\"C:\\R\\R-3.2.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe\"
           C:\\My_work\\R_scripts\\my_code.R my_args";

#my_args only needed if you script take `args`as input to run
```

other way is you declare header in your r script (my_code.r)

```
 #!/usr/bin/Rscript
```

and call it from command line

```
./my_code.r
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it in Git Bash terminal, you could follow a revised version of the idea suggested by @user5249203: in the first line of your file `my_code.R`, type the following

```
#!/c/R/R-3.2.2/bin/Rscript.exe
```

I assumed that your path to Rscript.exe is the one listed above `C:\R\R-3.2.2\bin`. For anyone having a different path to Rscript.exe in Windows, just modify the path-to-Rscript accordingly. After this modification of your R code, you could run it in the Git Bash terminal using `path-to-the-code/mycode.R`. I have tested it on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while using r the first time in VS Code, just after installing the language package (CRAN).

I restart the application and everything worked perfectly. I think restarting would work for you as well.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33719722)